# Ruby works, but gem command not found - via SSH

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm definitely missing something obvious, but using bash through ssh, I can't seem to get rubygems to work, even though I've installed several rubygems through cpanel on my remote server.

```
ruby --version
```

returns

```
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-06-29 patchlevel 370) [x86_64-linux]
```

Yet if I do

```
gem env
```

I get

```
bash: gem: command not found
```

What am I missing...? Surely if ruby works, gem should?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RubyGems is in standard installation since 1.9.x so you need to install RubyGems or use RVM or rbenv to use newer version.

Comment: That makes sense.. although I'm rather confused because my cpanel has the rubygems panel available, and apparently installed rubygems when I first opened that panel. Also, I don't have root priveledges.. I've put a support ticket in... thanks